# How to WriteProcessMemory with multipointers

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, offset

First of all, what I am trying to do is changing a value in the memory of a game.
In order to write to that variable I need to add the following pointer and offsets because then I always get to an address that works:

```
baseAddr + offset1 + offset2 + offset3 = myDesiredAddr
```

Now, this is what I have tried to do...

```
ReadProcessMemory(
hProc, (LPVOID)(BaseAddr + offset1), &myDesiredAddr, sizeof(myDesiredAddr), 0
);
ReadProcessMemory(
hProc, (LPVOID)(myDesiredAddr + offset2), &myDesiredAddr, sizeof(myDesiredAddr), 0
);
ReadProcessMemory(
hProc, (LPVOID)(myDesiredAddr + offset3), &myDesiredAddr, sizeof(myDesiredAddr), 0
);
```

I've tired to WriteProcessMemory on the final address that I got but it does not read and write successfully. Any advice will be helpful.

Comment: `ReadProcessMemory` provides both a return value and a way to get how much data is read, both of which you ignore.  Add some error checking.

Comment: No please, I do check if it succeeds. This is only quick example.

Comment: It's hard to give a read answer if you don't post the real code.  If you're getting an error, what is it?  Extremely important information to have.

Comment: I want to know if im walking in right direction when adding the offsets, or if its wrong thing to do...

Comment: I guess that the final address (`myDesiredAddr + offset3`) is not a valid address within `hProc`. It looks to me that you're trying to follow pointers of/to objects of that process to a final memory location. I doubt if this will work since the memory of the other process may change while you're reading thus rendering your final address invalid.

Comment: You're right @LukasThomsen that's what I'm trying to do. Ok thanks, your comment is useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
unsigned long offset1 =  /* your value              */
unsigned long offset2 =  /* your value              */
unsigned long offset3 =  /* your value              */
unsigned long BaseAddr = /* your value              */
unsigned long Pointer;   /* to hold the final value */
unsigned long temp;      /* hold the temp values    */
unsigned value =         /* value to write          */
```

The above shows your declarations. I presume you check if the read and write functions return successfully, otherwise I would suggest you do so.

```
ReadProcessMemory(
hProc, reinterpret_cast<LPVOID>(BaseAddr), &temp, sizeof(temp), 0);
Pointer = temp + offset1;

ReadProcessMemory(
hProc, reinterpret_cast<LPVOID>(Pointer), &temp, sizeof(temp), 0);
Pointer = temp + offset2;

ReadProcessMemory(
hProc, reinterpret_cast<LPVOID>(Pointer), &temp, sizeof(temp), 0);
Pointer = temp + offset3;

/* Now Pointer stores the final address and *
 * you can write to it                      */
WriteProcessMemory(
hProc, reinterpret_cast<unsigned*>(Pointer), &value, sizeof(value), 0);
```

By adding the memory addresses and offsets and storing the value in *Pointer*, you can continue to read from *Pointer* and store the temporary addresses in a *temp* variable until you get to the final address that you want.

I suggest you do this in a loop for efficiency and neater code.

Answer (score 0):

You write a function which walks the multilevel pointer, each step it de-references the pointer and adds the relative offset.

For this example I will use a simple assault cube cheat I've made

FindDMAAddy function (Find Dynamic Memory Allocation Address):

```C++
uintptr_t FindDMAAddy(HANDLE hProc, uintptr_t ptr, std::vector<unsigned int> offsets)
{
    uintptr_t addr = ptr;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < offsets.size(); ++i)
    {
        ReadProcessMemory(hProc, (BYTE*)addr, &addr, sizeof(addr), 0);
        addr += offsets[i];
    }
    return addr;
}
```

The main code:

```
    uintptr_t moduleBase = GetModuleBaseAddress(procId, L"ac_client.exe");

    //Get Handle to Process
    HANDLE hProcess = 0;
    hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, procId);

    //Resolve base address of the pointer chain
    uintptr_t dynamicPtrBaseAddr = moduleBase + 0x10f4f4;

    std::cout << "DynamicPtrBaseAddr = " << "0x" << std::hex << dynamicPtrBaseAddr << std::endl;

    //Resolve our ammo pointer chain
    std::vector<unsigned int> ammoOffsets = { 0x374, 0x14, 0x0 };
    uintptr_t ammoAddr = FindDMAAddy(hProcess, dynamicPtrBaseAddr, ammoOffsets);

    std::cout << "ammoAddr = " << "0x" << std::hex << ammoAddr << std::endl;
```

You can find a more complete version of my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58812227/8985046)