# Why I cannot write to the process memory (WriteProcessMemory)?

Tags: c++, winapi, readprocessmemory, process-injection

## Summary:

So basically I'm trying to read/write to the target process ConsoleApplication1.exe using `ReadProcessMemory`
and `WriteProcessMemory` functions in the winapi. I am able to read from the target process memory but I'm not able to write to the memory.

## Details:

`GetBaseAddress` (Process that is used to read/write to the memory)

## Code:

```cpp
// GetBaseAddress.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <psapi.h>
#include <processthreadsapi.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

DWORD FindID(char *name );
void errExit(const char msg[50], HANDLE handle = 0);
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    /*Find Process ID by Name*/
    char name[] = "ConsoleApplication1.exe";
    DWORD processID = FindID(name);
    HANDLE processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, processID);
    HANDLE snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, processID);
    if (snapshot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE || processHandle == NULL||processHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        errExit("Counldn't create snapshot exiting...", snapshot);
    }
    cout << "[+]Snapshot created for PID:" << processID << endl;
    cout << "[+]Retriving Module Info..." << endl;
    MODULEENTRY32 moduleEntry  ;
    moduleEntry.dwSize = sizeof(MODULEENTRY32);
    if (Module32First(snapshot, &moduleEntry) == FALSE) {
        errExit("Counldn't retrive entry exiting...",processHandle);
    }
    //stringstream address;
    //
    char buff[12] = "Hello World";
    DWORD offset = 0x19B44; //HelloWorld - [H]
    //
    //BYTE word = *moduleEntry.modBaseAddr;
    DWORD_PTR dwModuleBaseAddress = (DWORD_PTR)moduleEntry.modBaseAddr+offset;
    std::stringstream stream;
    stream << std::hex << dwModuleBaseAddress;
    std::string hexAddress = stream.str();
   
    cout << "[+]Base Address of the module is:" << hexAddress << endl;
    cout << "[+]Reading Memory..." << endl;
    BOOL rslt = ReadProcessMemory(processHandle, moduleEntry.modBaseAddr + offset, buff, sizeof(buff) - 1, NULL);
    if (rslt == FALSE) {
        errExit("Couldn't read memory region exiting...");
    }
    //char buff2[] = "Hacked     ";
    cout << "[+]Memory Data:" << buff << endl;
    cout << endl;
  
     rslt= WriteProcessMemory(processHandle, moduleEntry.modBaseAddr + offset,buff,sizeof(buff)-1,NULL);
    if (rslt == FALSE) {
        errExit("Couldn't write to the Memory Address");
    }
    
}

DWORD FindID(char *name) {
    cout << name << endl;
    DWORD procIDs[1024],needed=0;
    
    std::wstring str = L"ConsoleApplication1.exe";
    int rslt = EnumProcesses(procIDs, sizeof(procIDs), &needed);
    if (rslt==0) {
        errExit("Procees IDs list couldn't be retrived exiting...");
    }
    cout << "[+]Process IDs List Retrived..." << endl;
    cout << "[+]Bytes Returned:" << needed << endl;
    cout << "[+]sizeof(DWORD):" << sizeof(DWORD) << endl;
    cout << "[+]Number of Process Retrived:" << needed / sizeof(DWORD) << endl;
    
    for (int i = 0;i <= needed / sizeof(DWORD); i++) {
        HANDLE processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, procIDs[i]);
        if (processHandle == NULL) {
            //CloseHandle(processHandle);
            continue;
        }
        wchar_t processFileName[MAX_PATH];
        GetModuleBaseNameW(processHandle, NULL, processFileName, sizeof(processFileName));
        
        
        if (std::wstring(processFileName) == str) {
            cout << "[+]Found:" << procIDs[i] << endl;
            cout << "[+]Process " <<":" << i << endl;
            wcout << "[+]Process Name" << ":" << processFileName << endl;
            return procIDs[i];
        }
        CloseHandle(processHandle);
    }


}

void errExit(const char msg[50], HANDLE handle) {
    cout << "[-]"<<msg << endl;
    cout << "[-]Retriving Last Error:" << GetLastError() << endl;
    CloseHandle(handle);
    system("pause");
    exit(1);
}
```

Here I'm using `modEntry.modBaseAddr + offset` to read and write to the memory location of the target process.
`modEntry.modBaseAddr` holds the base address of the first module of the process and `modEntry.modBaseAddr + offset` is the location of the first character of the string *"Hello World"* located in the target process.

This is the error I'm getting with `WriteProcessMemory`:

```
998 - ERROR_NOACCESS
Invalid access to memory location.
```

## Things I've already tried:

**1. Using `VirtualProtect` function to change protect region returns `FALSE` with Old Protect being:**

```
-PAGE_NOACCESS
0x01
```

*According to Microsoft:*

> PAGE_NOACCESS
> 0x01

> Disables all access to the committed region of pages. An attempt to read from, write to, or execute the committed region results in an access violation.
> This flag is not supported by the CreateFileMapping function.

**2. Trying Multiple times - returns the same error**

**3. Using a hard-coded address - returns the same error**
I tried to set the address directly as `(LPVOID)0x619b44`
Here, `modEntry.modBaseAddr + offset = 0x619b44`

**4. Trying to CloseHandle and reopen the process using OpenProcess using PROCESS_VM_WRITE constraint - returns the same error**

## Here is the code for ConsoleApplication.exe (The target process in which I'm trying to overwrite data):

```
#include<Windows.h>
//#include<unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    HANDLE d = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    cout << "Module Handle:"<<d<<endl;
    int gold = 0;
    int* ptr = &gold;
    char buff[] = "Hello World\n";
    std::cout << buff;
    system("title hackme");
    std::cout << "Enter something:";
    std::cin >> gold;
    for (;;) {
        std::cout << buff;
        //gold++;
        std::cout << "Address:";
        std::cout << &gold<< std::endl;
        std::cout << gold << std::endl;
        Sleep(1000);
        
    }
    cout << "Congrats Pro!!!" << endl;

    
}
```

**OUTPUT for `GetBaseAddress`:**

[image: GetBaseAddress]

**OUTPUT for ConsoleApplication1.exe**

[image: ConsoleApplication1]

## Software Details:

1. Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
2. Version `16.11.23`
3. Optimization: Disabled
4. OS: Window 10

Comment: [Please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Program output is text. Post text as text.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36223809/write-in-another-process-memory-with-writeprocessmemory-and-a-pointer) might help.

Comment: Start by **properly** diagnosing the issue. `GetLastError` is a helpful tool, so long as it is used as designed. Specifically: **No** code in between observing the condition under which the last error code is valid and the call to `GetLastError`.

Comment: What makes you think that the correct address is `0x619b44`?

Comment: @Jabberwocky okay sorry i'll remember this next time :)

Comment: @IInspectable wdym i have put errExit function for every value ? is these something im missing ?

Comment: @RaymondChen I attached a debugger to find out that address. And also if it was a wrong address i shouldn't be able to read data from that address

Comment: Actually when i was trying to print the BaseAddress as cout << modEntry.modBaseAddr it was trying to access the memory location instead. Im sorry for the confusion actually the base address is 60 0000 and as for how i determined that offset is,
619B44 - 60 0000 = 19B44
is the address to the Hello World

Comment: @SUDOHERO You have hard-coded the offset as `0x19B44`, where did you get that value from? Nowhere in your `ConsoleApplication.exe` code are you outputting the address of your `buff` that you are trying to write to. `ConsoleApplication.exe` is printing out its true base address (but the screenshot you have provided is missing that info), whereas `GetBaseAddress` is printing out the *adjusted* address being accessed, not the base module address itself. Based on what has been shown, you are trying to access address `0x619B44`, is that the correct memory address of `buff`? We can't see that.

Comment: @SUDOHERO "*when i was trying to print the BaseAddress as `cout << modEntry.modBaseAddr` it was trying to access the memory location instead*" - that is because `modBaseAddr` is a `BYTE*` pointer, ie `unsigned char*`, and `operator<<` has overloads that treat all `[(un)signed] char*` pointers as null-terminated strings. You need to cast the pointer to `void*` to print the address itself: `cout << (void*) modEntry.modBaseAddr`. And FYI, you don't need to use `std::stringstream` to print a hex string to `std::cout`, you can use `std::hex` with `std::cout` directly.

Comment: this offest will be different for each machine you compile in you have to attach a debugger to a do the math as baseAddress - StringAddr = offset i have given you up how i got that

Comment: Ohh thanks for that. I was confused as why it is behaving like this for BYTE*.Cuz when i did this for DWORD it worked normally. Thanks bro i'll remember for next time :)

Comment: @SUDOHERO "*this offest will be different for each machine*" - yes, it can be, which is why you should not be hard-coding it at all.  Let the user enter the desired address/offset at runtime, and you should have `ConsoleApplication.exe` print out the correct address/offset, too. "*the math as `baseAddress - StringAddr = offset`*" - you have that backwards, it should be `StringAddr - baseAddress = offset` instead.

Comment: oh yeah sorry you are right i did'nt noticed that that's i wrote it incorrectly sorry for that. I still have much to learn :). I'll remember this things

Comment: Actually im not outputting the Address for ```buff``` the address is for ```gold``` variable. Sorry when took the screenshot i missed the ```Module Handle:[ADDRESS]``` part.

Comment: *"i have put errExit function for every value ? is these something im missing ?"* - Clearly. I emphasized "**No** code in between" which apparently went right past you. `cout << "Whatever"` **is** code.

Comment: I don't understand whoever closed it as a duplicate, did he/she even looked at the reference they provided i have clearly stated that i've already used VirtualProtect . It doesn't matter now i had already found the solution yesterday  i was just looking if someone has some alternative to this. I see people instead of trying for solution just talking here and there this missing that missing,etc. If someone needs the solution check here :https://www.unknowncheats.me/forum/programming-for-beginners/581349-write-process-memory-writeprocessmemory.html. I've had already provided everything needed.

Comment: But instead of looking for solution they are focusing on things missing that, before providing the question i knew are not even required cuz they and nothing to do with the problem. I appreciate the suggestion. Some things require common sense don't expect people to spoon feed you.